# Update columns if particular conditions are met in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to update my columns `copay` and `coinsurance`.

If for a particular patient suffix the `patient_pay` does not changes and `ingredient_cost` changes, then it should copy the value of `patient_pay` into the `Copay` column.

Also, if for a particular `patient_suffix` the ingredient cost changes but ratio of `patient_pay` and `ingredient_cost` remains constant, then it should copy the value of ratio into the `coinsurance` column.

```
Row_num -- Patient_Suffix --- Patient_Pay--- Ingredient_Cost ---   Ratio  -----   Copay ----- Coinsurance

1    --        A      --       15      --       352.37         
1    --        A      --       15      --       352.37                                    
1    --        A      --       15      --       352.37                                        
1    --        A      --       15      --       368.15                                              
1    --        A      --       15      --       368.15                                            
2    --        B      --     315.11    --       315.48                                             
2    --        B      --     346.26    --       346.71   
2    --        B      --     346.23    --       346.71
```

So I want 15 to be updated in `Copay` for `Patient_Suffix` A and ratio of `patient_pay` and `Ingredient_Cost` in Ratio column and same ratio in rows having `Patient_Suffix` B in `Coinsurance` column.

My code:

```
declare @t INT

SET @t = 1

WHILE @t <= (SELECT count(distinct Patient_Suffix) from @temp)
BEGIN
    IF (select count(distinct Patient_Pay) from @temp where Patient_Suffix = (select distinct(Patient_Suffix) from @temp where Row_num = @t )) = 1 and (select count(distinct Ingredient_Cost) from @temp where Patient_Suffix = (select distinct(Patient_Suffix) from @temp where Row_num = @t )) > 1 
        UPDATE @temp
        SET Copay = Patient_pay

        SET @t = @t + 1
END
```

But it goes into infinite loop with @t = 1 and value of @t does not show any increment.

Desired Output :
   Row_num -- Patient_Suffix --- Patient_Pay--- Ingredient_Cost ---   Ratio  -----   Copay ----- Coinsurance

```
1    --        A      --       15      --       352.37     --    0.042      --   15
1    --        A      --       15      --       352.37     --    0.042      --   15         --     NULL             
1    --        A      --       15      --       352.37     --    0.042      --    15        --     NULL               
1    --        A      --       15      --       368.15     --    0.040       --    15        --     NULL                               
1    --        A      --       15      --       368.15     --    0.040       --   15         --     NULL                           
2    --        B      --     315.11    --       315.48     --    0.998       --  NULL        --     0.998                                  
2    --        B      --     346.26    --       346.71     --    0.998         --  NULL        --     0.998 
2    --        B      --     346.23    --       346.71     --    0.998        --  NULL        --     0.998
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Why are you using a loop anyway? Sql works best with a set based approach. Please edit your question to include the relevant table's DDL, some sample data as DML statement, and desired results.

Comment: actually the original data contains more than 5 lakhs rows and more than 24000 different patient suffix. So I thought the best way to update my Copay column by using loop until loop reaches the last unique patient_suffix.
I have updated the desired Copay and Coinsurance values in their respective columns.